# Database install approach - attach MDF or restore BAK

Tags: sql-server, database, installation, mdf

I have some pre-built databases that go with a base software release.

Previously we have released the MDFs and a little tool to copy/attach them, and just letting SQL Server rebuild the log file.

Is releasing the backup BAK files and modifying the tool to restore them a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i like to backup and restore, but that is just personal preference. 
Either method works and if you already have a tool to attach the data files, then i'd just go with what you already have.